# Expand the complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I need to "expand"[not sure if this is the best word] this $(i*e)^\sqrt{2}$.

I thought that would be a good idea expand it using the principal Logarithm, so that, $(ie)^\sqrt{2} = e^{\sqrt{2}*Log{ie}} = e^{\sqrt{2}*(1+i(4k\pi + \pi)/2)} = e^{\sqrt{2}+i(4k\pi + \pi)/\sqrt{2}}$

Since some arithmetic rules involving Log are different from the usual/real log, i decided to let the answer just like i presented above.

Unfortunatelly, the book gives the answer as $e^{i(4k\pi + \pi)/\sqrt{2}}$. I can't see how it got this answer, so i am posting this question in order to clarify my doubts.

Is my approach right? and the book answer? if both are right, how can i go from the answer i got to the answer provided by the book?

Comment: I think your answer is right?

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $a^b$, for $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ with $a\ne0$, denotes any complex number obtained as
$$
\exp(b\log a)
$$
where $\log a$ is any complex number such that $\exp(\log a)=a$.

Usually an exception is made when $a=e$, where $e^z$ is an alias for $\exp z$.

Thus you want to compute the (multivalued) complex logarithm of
$$
ie=ei=e(\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2))
$$
(the number has been expressed in polar form) and we therefore know that
$$
\log(ie)=1+i\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\Bigr)
$$
(real logarithm of the modulus plus $i$ times any possible value of the argument).

Now apply the definition above to see that
$$
(ie)^{\sqrt{2}}=\exp\Bigl(\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\Bigr)\Bigr)
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think what you've got is right.
$$(i*e)^\sqrt{2}$$
$$i= e^{i\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}}$$
$$(i*e)^\sqrt{2}=(e^{i\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}}* e^1)^{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=(e^{i\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}+1})^{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=(e^{\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(4k+1)\pi+\sqrt{2}})$$

EDIT: Checked on [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28i*e%29%5E%28sqrt%282%29%29), it's definitely a printing error in your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above it is a printing error, but here is another way to solve the problem.
Note that $(ie)^\sqrt{2} = e^\sqrt{2} \cdot i^\sqrt{2}$ and that $i = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}+2ki\pi}$, therefore $i^\sqrt{2} = (e^{i\frac{\pi+4k\pi}{2}})^\sqrt{2} = e^{i\frac{\pi+4k\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}$.

Therefore we have that $(ie)^\sqrt{2} = e^\sqrt{2} \cdot e^{i\frac{\pi+4k\pi}{\sqrt{2}}} = e^{\sqrt{2} + i\frac{\pi+4k\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}$

Comment: Definitely not: it is NOT true, in general, that $(uv)^a = u^a v^a$ for complex $u,v$ and real $a$.

Comment: @AlexM. Could you provide a counterexample? it seems to me that any 2 complex numbers can be represented as $u = r_1e^{i\theta_1}, v = r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ therefore $(uv)^a = (r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)})^a = r_1^ar_2^ae^{ia(\theta_1+\theta_2)} = r_1^ae^{ia\theta_1} \cdot r_2^ae^{ia\theta_2} = u^av^a$. Maybe I am missing something trivial.